# 2N digit number with exactly N ones and N zeros. Prove there exists a number divisible by N

Tags: number-theory

Given a decimal number 2N digits long, but containing exactly N ones (1s) and N zeros (0s). Prove (or disprove) there exists an arrangement of the N 1s such that N is a divisor of the 2N digit number. The problem requires that the MSD always contain a 1. (Otherwise the specification of a 2N digit number would be ambiguous). Note, this is not asking if ALL arrangements of the N digits produces a 2N digit number divisible by N. Rather, it is asking if there exists SOME arrangement of the N digits causing the 2N digit number to be divisible by N.

I'm adding some thoughts I had on this.

- A 1 at the ith digit (Di) represents the ith power of 10. The 2N digit number will be divisible by N if SUM(Di)=0(mod N)
- Successive powers (in natural sequence) of 10 will generate all p-1 residues Mod N if 10 is a primitive root of N= p= prime number.
- A full set of p-1 residues has a sum=0 (mod N=p)
- In this case we need one more 1 for the full N 1 digits. It's effect can be cancelled because we have a complete set of residues. We still maintain Sum=0 mod p, by deleting one Di of them and adding 2 such that their sum = the deleted Di.
- So problem is soluble when N is prime and 10 is a primitive root of N.
- If 10 is not primitive (N still prime), the cycle length of successive powers is less than p-1, where cycle length is a divisor of p-1. In this case we cannot necessarily delete one and find 2 whose sum mod p is the same. That is because only a subset of residues is available.
- More complications are when considering non sequential arrangements and composite N

Comment: A deceptively simple problem. If a counterexample exists, it must be odd.

Comment: @Anthony:  Why must a counterexample be odd?

Comment: @Jason: Wow, this is such a deep, fascinating problem. As I think more about it, I realize that I can only rule out numbers that are not 3-smooth. If $n = 2^j$ then all you have to do is clump the zeros together at the end. If $n = 3^k$ then any arrangement with a one as most significant works. And if $n = 2^j 3^k$, any arrangement with a one as most significant and a zero as least significant works.

Comment: @Anthony:  Agreed.  I think for you last sentence, you need to trail with at least $j$ $0$s, not just one at the end.  Incidentally, does anyone know what number works when $n = 7$?  The next case which requires any work at all is $n=11$.

Comment: @Andres: I believe number-theory tag is appropriate for this (at least based on one answer)...

Comment: @Aryabhata Sure. I've switched the tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This follows from the [Erdos-Ginsburg-Ziv](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Erd%C3%B6s-Ginzburg-Ziv_theorem) theorem:

> Any set of $2N-1$ integers, has a subset of size exactly $N$, such
>   that the sum of elements of that set is divisible by $N$.

You can take your set to be $\{2^0, 2^1, \dots, 2^{2N-1}\}$ and the sum of the $N$ element subset will be $2N-1$ bit number with exactly $N$ ones.

A proof of that theorem can be seen here: http://uniformlyatrandom.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/the-erdos-ginzburg-ziv-theorem/

Comment: The set could be a multiset.