# Can we prove that there exists a number having only digits $0$ and $1$ with $k$ $1$’s that is divisible by $k$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I was trying to proof the following theorem:

> For all $k$ element of the set of natural numbers, there exists a zero
> one number that has exactly $k$ $1$’s that is divisible by $k$.
>
> For example, if $k=3$, then the number can be $1011$, which *is* divisible by
> $k$.

It is easy to construct such a number for a given integer, but how do we prove the existence of such a number for any integer?

Comment: If you can construct one for a given integer isn't that a proof? Or do you mean you can do it in an ad hoc way each time you try?

Comment: I mean the latter.

Comment: Maybe useful: Using the Pigeonhole principle you can prove that there exists a number of the form $11...10...0$ which is divisible by $k$ (where the number of $1's$ may not be $k$).

Comment: Maybe useful'er: Can also show that the number $11...10...0$ has a multiple of $k$ many $1$'s

Comment: here someone ask a question that is even stronger than yours https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095770/2n-digit-number-with-exactly-n-ones-and-n-zeros-prove-there-exists-a-number-div?rq=1

Comment: This one worked out for me :)
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $k'$ be the largest natural number satisfying $k' \ | \ k$ and $\gcd(k', 10) = 1$. Let me tell you how to deal with $k' = k$, and it should not be too hard to get to the general case.

By Euler's theorem, $10^{\phi(k)} \equiv 1 \pmod k$. So $1 + 10^{\phi(k)} + 10^{2\phi(k)} + \cdots + 10^{(k-1)\phi(k)}$ is divisible by $k$, and is what you need.